# Getting null result on page using angularjs function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

call other page on finish click event :-

```
<a class="btn btn-default finish" style="display:none" ng-click="result()"  onclick="alert('Thank you ..');">Finish</a>
```

My html code look like below for other page :-

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages" ng-init="result()">
<div class="all_ques_back col-md-12" ng-repeat="ans in correctAnswer">
<div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x col_padd   wrong_ans_font"></i></div>
<div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10 col_padd"><div class="all_ques" ng-repeat=" (key, val) in ans">hello your ans {{val}}</div></div>
<div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col_padd"><i class="fa fa-angle-right right_arrow"></i></div>
</div>    
</div>
```

and my controller code look like below :-

```
$scope.correctAnswer = [];
$scope.result = function () {

$(".optionlist").find("li").each(function () {

if ($(this).attr('id') == 'true') { 
var label = $(this).parent('ul').attr('que-label');
var value = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('value');

$scope.correctAnswer.push({ "label": label }, { "Option": value });

}
});

console.log($scope.correctAnswer);
$location.path("/reviewans");

}
```

Comment: First you should never use JQuery inside angular JS. To get the value of an input try to use the ng-model directive to bind the input value to your javascript var. Secondly : What is actually not working ? What error do you have ?

Comment: Do not mix jQuery and angular if you are not absolutely sure that you have to. In 99% of cases there is a clean angular-only way to do what you want

Comment: ok .. can you pls.check link : - plnkr.co/edit/haEthPQ7Z841e76jAgXj?p=preview here i'd create one demo now in the demo i'm getting result in console two times instead of one...by the way my question is what's going wrong in my code ??? how can i get console result only once..

Answer (score 0):

The function on the controller are looking for a "li" tag, but on html you define the ngRepeat on a "div" tag. The ngRepeat will repeat all the HTML code at tag it's defined on. So, you can try:

```
<div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10 col_padd"><ul><li class="all_ques" ng-repeat=" (key, val) in ans">hello your ans {{val}}</li></ul></div>
```

Like Okazari commented, don't use Jquery inside your angularJs code. I recommend to take a time to read angularJS docs. It's pretty easy to learn. And about ngRepeat, you can see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: ok .. can you pls.check link : - http://plnkr.co/edit/haEthPQ7Z841e76jAgXj?p=preview here i'd create one demo now in the demo i'm getting result in console two times instead of one...by the way my question is what's going wrong in my code ??? how can i get console result only once...